# Get all a elements inside td's from a div outside the table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

I'm currently strugling of how to get all the `A` elements inside which are inside a `td` which is inside a `table` which is inside a repeated `div`.

So this is the format of my html code

[image]

And i want each `a` element in a variable and below i'm going to click all these elements with a function that I have, but don't mind about that.

So I've tried this

```
var scrl = document.getElementsByClassName("uiScrollableAreaContent");
var circleditems = scrl[scrl.length-1].getElementsByClassName("_1pu2 _1pu4");
```

But it clearly doesn't get the `a` elements.
Any idea of how to do it in Javascriot (not in jquery) ??

Thanks a lot~

Comment: `var scrl = document.getElementsByClassName("uiScrollableAreaContent");
[].forEach.call(scrl, function(el) {
  var aElems = el.getElementsByClassName("_1pu2 _1pu4");
  console.log(aElems);
});
`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".uiScrollableAreaContent table.uiGrid a")`

Comment: @Andreas actually it has to be in the specific order that it is on the image, because with your query selector All it clicks ALL the `a` elements that are in any scrollable area. Forgot to say that tis ui scrollable area is and in other places inside the page :(

Comment: @Rayon see the comment above it is the same for you too :D

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios — How order is violated in code I have provided ?

Comment: @Rayon because `scrollable area content` is also elsewhere and it also has `_1pu2` inside. Although QuerySelectorAll with a small change it does exactly what i need

Comment: @Andreas can you please answer the question with your code so i can accept it? Thanks :)

Comment: Sure, but I only showed you a possible tool so feel free to add your actual solution as an answer.

Comment: @Andreas you just have to add `._1pt_` after `.uiScrollableAreaContent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be solvable with [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

*Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of [selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). The object returned is a NodeList.*

---

The function accepts a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). So this should give you the links you're looking for:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".uiScrollableAreaContent ._1pt_ table.uiGrid a._1pu2._1pu4");
```

A small example:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".uiScrollableAreaContent ._1pt_ table.uiGrid a._1pu2._1pu4");
links.forEach(l => l.classList.add("highlight"));
```

```css
.highlight { background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<div class="uiScrollableAreaContent">
  <div class="_1pt_">
    <table class="uiGrid">
    <tbody>
      <tr><td><a href="#" class="">1</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td><a href="#" class="_1pu2 _1pu4">2</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td><a href="#" class="">3</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td><a href="#" class="_1pu2 _1pu4">4</a></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="_1pu2 _1pu4">lorem ipsum</a>
  </p>
</div>
```